# MVC3 RenderPartial and the ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewbag

I'll try to keep this brief:

In the view

```
@Html.RenderPartial("myview", Model.SubModel, 
     new ViewDataDictionary()
     {
          { "thing", Model.Thing }
     })
```

In the myview we see that "thing" is avaiable, i.e. this produces the value of Model.Thing in the myview view:

```
@ViewBag.thing
```

Great! Simple

But I need to do something with thing (and thing can't be part of SubModel by the way), i.e. access this in my view engine or ideally in the controller, e.g.:

```
public ActionResult myview(SubModelType vm)
{
    var thing = ViewBag.thing; // oh dear this doesnt exist.. but is there when the view is rendered
```

So my question is, if the ViewBag is available in the resulting myview, it must be being passed around somehow in the httpcontext, or in the controllercontext somewhere right?  Does anyone know why it's not available in the controller but is in the view and how I might be able to access this?

### Edit

Sorry I missed a vital point here! It's when "myview" is posted back to the controller, invoking an action called myview where I would expect the ViewBag rendered to myview to be available.  But of course it's not, it's been used in "myview" and that's it.  So if I want to use it in the myview action I'm going to need to store in the ViewBag in that view OR set some value of the viewmodel so that it can be posed back to the action.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How do you expect to read some value in the controller that is available only inside the views which are rendered much after the main controller has finished executing? Could you provide an example of what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would expect the ViewBag data to be available at some point in either the controller rendering the view or the view engine.  Without going into too much detail on the why: there is data which i do not wish to store in the model which i need to be available in the controller. A work around is to add it to the SubModel in the initial view, e.g. Model.SubModel.Dict.Add("thing", 123). But I want to avoid logic like this in my view. The ViewBag data should be available prior to view rendering in the ControllerConext (or HttpContext), otherwise how does it get to the view?

Comment: The ViewData is a property of the View and the ControllerContext. That's how it gets to the view. But in your case you are passing it to a partial view from within a main view. The controller has absolutely no relation here. The controller has been long garbage collected when this happens. You want this value to be passed back to the controller when some form is submitted or within an AJAX request? Please forgive my stupidity but I still do not understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The 'subview' or partial has a completely different scope for a reason.

Comment: @MrAH, is your priority to understand why this happens or to find a way to work around?

Comment: Sorry everyone - i've misssed a VITAL point here.  It's actually a slightly different problem.  I fully understand what you are saying about the fact that I am past the controller stage.

Comment: @DaveA - sorry please see my edit.  it's actually on the submit/post of the myview model back to the controller where I was expecting the ViewBag set at the point of rendering myview to be the same ViewBag available within the action I'm posting to.  1) render view, 2) render partial view with additional viewdata, 3) post partial view to controller, 4) get data in step 2 within this action.  I can see an obvious way to workaround this now, but expected the ViewBag to persist (probably stupidly)

Comment: Ok, here we go back to @DarinDimitrov s point. Viewbag is out of scope here. Viewbag is a member of Controller class. Once you're in a new instance of Controller, your old one is out of scope and/or grabage collected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sorry I missed a vital point here! It's when "myview" is posted back
>   to the controller, invoking an action called myview where I would
>   expect the ViewBag rendered to myview to be available.

Oh no, you cannot be possibly expecting anything like that. That's not how ASP.NET MVC works. When you send an HTTP request to a controller action the default model binder will intercept this request and look in the posted values from the request and bind them to your action argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myview(SubModelType vm, ThingViewModel thing)
{
    ...
}
```

This obviously assumes that those *thing* values were part of the original request. So for example if you submit a form you should include corresponding fields inside this form that the model binder could use.

Think of it that way: an ASP.NET MVC controller action could be invoked from any client. For example from an iPhone application. And as you know there's no such notion as `ViewBag` in iOS. All that will happen is that the default model binder will look at the POSTed values and attempt to hydrate the view models that your action is taking as arguments.

If on the other hand you cannot make those *thing* values as part of the request (by including corresponding input fields in the form) you could only send the ID of this *thin* from a hidden field and then inside your controller action use this ID to query your underlying data-store to retrieve the *thing* from the same place you retrieved it initially when you first rendered this form.

Some people might also suggest you storing the *Thing* inside the Session and then reading the value back from the Session in your POST action. I am not from those people. It's an alternative approach though.

Comment: Excellent thanks, yes I had tied myself in knots a bit there I think, i am fully aware that we are only talking about html form data and if I've not explicitly added my "thing" value to the data to be posted (i.e. by adding it to the view model being rendered or to the "new" ViewBag in the partial view) then I can't expect it to be available to the action method